# Reuse select result in the same query

Tags: mysql, select, reusability

I have a query like this:

```
DELETE FROM rules_table
WHERE
    type1 = (
        SELECT type_id
        FROM types_table
        WHERE name = '<some_name>')
OR
    type2 = (
        SELECT type_id
        FROM types_table
        WHERE name = '<some_name>')
```

*Please note that `<some_name>` is the same in both occurrences*

I submit a query from php script and I'd prefer it to be a single request rather then selecting the type_is with one request, parsing the result and submitting the delete request.

And also as far as I know, running the same `SELECT` statement two times is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
DELETE FROM rules_table
WHERE  (
         SELECT type_id
         FROM types_table
         WHERE name = '<some_name>'
       ) in (type1, type2)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Thank you, this answer have made my day.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `subquery` you can use `INNER JOIN`:

```
DELETE a
FROM rules_table a
     INNER JOIN types_table b
        ON (a.type1 =  b.type_id OR a.type2 =  b.type_id)
WHERE b.name = '<some_name>';
```

Comment: Won't it delete row from the types_table?

Comment: no it will only delete records from table `rules_table a`  as we have given alias to it `DELETE a`.

Comment: oh, yes, I haven't noticed that :)